# Need to change the favicon in React JS into the public folder

Tags: html, reactjs

I have to change Favicon in react JS. but i want to add favicon from outside of the public folder. Can i add the favicon image path outside of the public folder.
for Example :
we have this by default :

i need like this :

Need to get path for favicon from outside of the Public folder.

Comment: This may help you
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel#icon